# Android Custom Calendar Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, calendar, android-alertdialog

So I'm putting together an application that needs a date set, and I have had just an absolutely horrid time with this application because of my lack of understanding of Fragments.

What I'm trying to do is create a custom alert dialog that contains a calendar, which I will then set the listener and pass the date information back to my input activity.

I've looked at the essential tutorial for Dialogs ([here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)), and I've managed to successfully create a basic alert, register clicks, and pass information from those clicks to my activity.

However, when I try to implement a custom view, as the site describes, when I click the button to bring up the dialog, I'm given the following message in my Logcat, and my application essentially freezes.

> I/AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's

I have looked and tried, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to get around this problem.

Here is my Dialog code...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;




public class TestDateDialog extends DialogFragment {
    TestDialogListener testListener;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_calendar_dialog, null));
        builder.setMessage("This is a test dialog!!");

        //Set action buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Log.d("Test", "Test OK Click!");
                testListener.onDialogPositiveClick(
                        "OK Button Clicked!");
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Log.d("Test", "Test Cancel Click!");
                testListener.onDialogNegativeClick(
                        "Cancel Button Clicked!!");
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {

            testListener = (TestDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {

            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                                                 + " must implement TestDialogListener");
        }
    }

    public interface TestDialogListener {
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(String text);
        public void onDialogNegativeClick(String text);
    }
}
```

Here is my very basic layout for the calendar...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id = "@+id/calendar_layout"
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    android:orientation = "vertical" >

    <CalendarView
        android:id = "@+id/input_calendar"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:showWeekNumber = "false" />
</LinearLayout >
```

Is there any way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the standard Android library for some classes and the support library for others. Notably, Activity and DialogFragment. Have you looked into converting those to support library?